# Connection pooling in Entity Framework 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, connection-pooling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework and Connection Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling)

Does EF1 support Connection Pooling? If yes, what we need to do to manage it?

Comment: What is the DB server? In particular, `SqlClient` (in ADO.NET) will handle pooling a few layers down for the SQL-Server case...

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling It is same for EFv1 and SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do anything except to make sure your connection string throughout the application stays the same.  .NET will take care of the rest herself.

Comment: This depends on what the server is, as this is determined by the specific implementation - not automatically in ADO.NET.

Comment: Considering the  tags asp.net AND entity-framework, the assumption is that we're talking about MS SQL Server.

Comment: why? ASP.NET and EF work on a *range* of databases... that being one of the key design choices between EF and L2S... it is an *options*, but it isn't known (and frankly, the DB vendor is a lot more important than the ASP.NET in this)

Comment: Let's just say that was my assumption/intuition.  ok?

Comment: @Kon, Yes, I am using SQL Server 2008. Any link where I can read more about this auto pooling done by EF or ADO.Net ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling

Answer (score 1):

Connection pooling is supported by EF and it is default. If you want to change it you can alter Pooling parameter in the connection string true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, somewhere underneath the EF code, a SqlConnection is created using a connection string. A pool of connections will be created per connection string.

It should simply work, without any code / config on your side